# Cannot center text when programmatically creating view from adaptor

Tags: android, gridview, textview, imageview

I am using an adaptor to generate a view for each of several items. The view needs to show an image with centered text below it. I create a linear layout and add an image view and text view.

To show the problem I have changed the background colors to green for the linear layout and red for the text view...

[image]

Obviously the text is showing left aligned instead of centered. Here is the simple code in the adaptor GetView method...

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(_context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        imageView.LayoutParameters = imageViewParam;
        imageView.Id = 1000 + position;
        imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Code);

        TextView textView = new TextView(_context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        textView.LayoutParameters = textViewParam;
        textView.Text = OPTIONS_TEXT[position];
        textView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
        textView.SetForegroundGravity(GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);

        LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(_context);
        linear.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 172);
        linear.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);
        linear.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        linear.AddView(imageView);
        linear.AddView(textView);

        return linear;
    }
```

As far as I can work out, you cannot set the **layout_gravity** setting when generating the view programmatically and so I tried setting the foreground gravity but has no effect at all.

I have tried everything I can think of but nothing gets that text centered!

Comment: You don't want the foreground gravity, just the regular gravity – `textView.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal`, it looks like it should be.

Comment: Cool, that was easy. Shame the documentation is so poor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set gravity center to LinearLayout.LayoutParams of TextView i.e.

```
 textViewParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```